# Queue System for Registration JSP

Tags: performance, jsp, load, tomcat6

I have a registration website in JSP (Server: Tomcat), how can I limit how many users can see registration page (Like 10 users ) ...and after that users will get in a Queue ..so that my website performance is not hit.

I have seen this kind of system in Prometric..so kind of wondering how can I also achieve the same using Java..

Comment: The performance of a web site is generally considered by its users as inversely proportional to the time they wait to get the web page they asked. If you put them in a queue whereas you have plenty of CPU time available, your performance will suffer, not increase.

Comment: @JB Nizet : I agree, But i was looking more of a logic how to implement such a scenario...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea, but if you really have to do it, then use a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) initialized with 10 permits, acquire the semaphore at the beginning of the servlet/jsp/action, and release it, in a finally block, when the servlet/jsp/action has ended its work.

You might also do this in a Filter, to decouple the access limitation code from the functional code.